# How to determine SVG path neighbours?

Tags: javascript, svg, jvectormap

I've been working with the great [JVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) library. When the user selects a particular country on the map, I'd like to be able to determine which countries are neighbouring or sharing a border.

My searches for calculating distances between SVG paths hasn't gotten me anywhere. Can anyone suggest a good solution to determine which countries are neighbours and which aren't?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be an array that lists a country and its bordering country names. Then use the array to filter your results. Creating the array would not be difficult since the following site lists bordering countries in a table:
[Land borders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_territories_by_land_borders)

This could take a few hours, but I'm sure others would appreciate your work:)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that Country shapes are svg path elements you could check those Countries (paths) have coinciding vertices or with a distance within a given threshold.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a functionality to do this directly in jvectormaps. But what you can do is apply a and incrementing value on each horizontal or vertical strip of regions (call it something like data-adj), and you can do something like:

```
for( i in regions ){
    if (Math.abs(this.data-adj - region[i].data-adj) <= 1){
        //is adjacent so do something
    }
}
```

This would really only work if you're looking for adjacency and not something like how many regions over a region is.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to find out the same thing, so i made this: https://github.com/FnTm/country-neighbors

It mainly contains a single json file, that describes land-based neighbors for most of the world.

For most cases, it should do what you need to do.